# amadeus api where if the list of all cityCodes

Tags: api, amadeus

In Amadeus API the is often a reference to "cityCode"

The documentation give this example
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=PAR&adults=1&radius=5&radiusUnit=KM&paymentPolicy=NONE&includeClosed=false&bestRateOnly=true&view=FULL&sort=PRICE

Where is the list of ALL cityCode ???

for this example it seems PAR refers to PARIS

is this https://service.unece.org/trade/locode/fr.htm

is there a cvs format of all city codes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Airport & City Search](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/airport-and-city-search) API to find an IATA code based on a city name

Otherwise, [this website](https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/IATA_Codes/IATA_Code_P.htm) provides a list of IATA city codes.